# How to solve the below issue in css , as I could not change the class name "parent 0-item"

Tags: css

I'm getting an error as "Unexpected token '.0' ". Suggest an alternate solution to solve this. As I'm getting the class as "parent 0-item".

```
.parent 0-item
  {
    pointer-events: none !important;
    cursor: default;
  }
```

Comment: I think it is supposed to be `.parent.0-item`. Since from what I understood, those classes are from the same element

Comment: I am assuming that 0-item is class. Add  .(dot) to )-item..  `.0-item`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Comment: In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A1 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you just receive the class name and have no control over the rendered HTML. If that's the case, then you can use an attribute selector.

```css
[class='parent 0-item'] {
    pointer-events: none !important;
    cursor: default;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent 0-item">
    Hello World!
</div>
```